# What floating point implementation details are required by the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, language-lawyer

Exactly what floating point implementation details are required by the C++11 standard?

Is some version of IEEE 754 required by the C++ standard?

Where is this stated in the C++ standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard does not require any particular floating point representation. [basic.fundamental]/8:

> The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined.

However, as IEEE 754 is very common, support can be checked via [`std::numeric_limits<>::is_iec559`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559).

Comment: Do all of the descriptions of the floating point implementation in `numeric_limits` need to be provided?

Comment: @Praxeolitic Yes, by the implementation. [limits.numeric]/2: "Specializations shall be provided for each arithmetic type, both floating point and integer, including bool."